# Unable to rename mipmap/icon to ic_launcher?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

When i try to rename @mipmap/icon to @mipmap/ic_launcer in authenticator.xml on line 2. Any program changes back when i build my app.

```
    * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  C:\ES.eWarrant\eWarrant\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\xml\authenticator.xml:2: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/icon (aka io.ionic.starter:mipmap/icon) not found.
```

This is an error i've got when want to build ionic app.

Ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.12.0 (C:\Users\ES property\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.4
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 8.0.0, browser 5.0.4, ios 5.0.0, windows 4.4.2
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 18 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\ES-Property\AppData\Local\Android\sdk)
   NodeJS            : v8.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 3.10.10
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: this file is available in your resource folder?

Comment: If u mean resources/ic_launcher.png yes.

Comment: @PeroPeric please check `mipmap/icon` file, is it there?

Comment: when i back android version to 7.1.1 i've got: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
   > Could not find intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.jar

Comment: questions and answers here may causing confusion. please list all files in resource, that is the best way. when you mention @mipmap/ic_launcher, you need the file ic_launcher.png in either mipmap or mipmap-### directories.

Answer (score 3):

What I did was copy one of the folders mipmap-whathever on /platforms/android/app/app/src/main/res changin the name to mipmap an the ic_launcher.png to icon.png